# how to use yocto sdcard image

Tags: yocto, u-boot

I am very new to yocto world, I am following below instructions to compile yocto.

http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-custom-embedded-linux-image.html

When I compiled yocto(boot2qt) from qt repository I got sdcard image. When I flashed sdcard to memory card I observed that there is no files in `/boot/` directory kernel and dtb files are present in another partition `mmc1p1`. My u-boot configuration is as below

```
setenv bootargs 'console=ttymxc1,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait fixrtc rw'
setenv bootcmd 'mmc dev 1; ext2load mmc 1:2 10800000 /boot/zImage;ext2load mmc 1:2 0x12000000 /boot/imx6q-sabrelitesd.dtb; bootz 0x10800000 - 0x12000000'
saveenv
```

And its not booting because there is no files in `/boot/` directory. Then I changed my uboot configuration as below

```
setenv bootcmd 'mmc dev 1; ext2load mmc 1:2 10800000 /zImage;ext2load mmc 1:2 0x12000000 /imx6q-sabrelitesd.dtb; bootz 0x10800000 - 0x12000000'
```

and I am getting file not found error, so its clear that I have mentioned 
`root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` and I am trying to load kernel from `mmc0p1`

How to fix this issue? Should I have to do something on yocto configuration and make kernel and dtb files to be available in `/boot/` directory or I have to change u-boot configuration to load kernel from different partition and rootfs from different partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are still trying to load kernel and dtb from partition 2, you have to update bootcmd. And as per my knowledge with yocto  partition1 will be in FAT file system so you have to use fatload.

```
setenv bootcmd 'mmc dev 1; fatload mmc 1:1 10800000 /zImage; fatload mmc 1:1 0x12000000 /imx6q-sabrelitesd.dtb; bootz 0x10800000 - 0x12000000'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using `.SDCARD` image from yocto. So then follow the below command to flash your image to sdcard. First delete all your sdcard partitions and umount the sdcard. then use `lsblk` command to know the `/dev/sdb|c|d` or `mmcblk0` etc

```
sudo dd if=fsl-image-gui-<MACHINE_NAME>.sdcard of=/dev/sd[b|c|d|e] bs=1MB
```